# Client-server application in Java - singleton issue

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, static, client-server

I have a client-server clock application in Java. The server sends time data to all connected clients, each connection running on a separate thread. The timed event is managed by ClockTask, which is singleton, so that all connection threads have access to the same server time:

```
public class ClockTask extends TimerTask {

private Calendar calendar;
private String time;
private static ClockTask instance = null;


public static ClockTask getInstance()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        return new ClockTask();
    }
    else return instance;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}


public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}


public ClockTask()
{
    this.calendar = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("us", "US"));

}


@Override
public void run() {

    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");                   
    this.time = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    //System.out.println(time);
}


public void setCalendarTime(String newTime)
{
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");   
    try {
        Date t = dateFormat.parse(newTime);
        calendar.setTime(t);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}
```

Now, if a client sends a request to change server time, it works fine. Server sets its new time, and all connected clients get a new, updated time. What I don't understand, is why, if I connect a new client (after setting a new time), the new client has its current time again, and Server resets its time to the one of the newly connected client.

My Server code, together with its connection thread:
The server loops indefinitely, waiting for new clients, if a client connects to the socket, it starts a new thread.

```
 public class Server {



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        boolean listeningSocket = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(11111);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 11111");
        }


        while(listeningSocket){

            System.out.println("Waiting for a client to connect...");
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client connected!");
            ConnectThread ct = new ConnectThread(clientSocket);                     
            ct.start();

        }
        System.out.println("closed");
        serverSocket.close();       
    }

}
```

The connect thread uses an existing ClockTask instance to get and send the current server time.

```
public class ConnectThread extends Thread{

public static final int INTERVAL = 1000;

static ClockTask ctask;


private Socket socket = null;
public ConnectThread(Socket socket) {
    super("ConnectThread");
    this.socket = socket;
    ConnectThread.ctask = ClockTask.getInstance();
    System.out.println(ctask.getTime());

}

@Override
public void run(){
    ObjectOutputStream serverOutputStream = null;
    ObjectInputStream serverInputStream = null;
    try {           
        serverOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());          
        serverInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(ctask, 0, INTERVAL);

        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
            System.out.println(ctask.getTime());
            serverOutputStream.writeUTF(ctask.getTime());               
            serverOutputStream.flush();
            String ok = serverInputStream.readUTF();
            if(ok.equals("ok"))
            {

                String newTime = serverInputStream.readUTF();
                ctask.setCalendarTime(newTime);
            }

        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            serverOutputStream.close();
            serverInputStream.close();              
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
}
```

The client reads the time and updates it in the GUI. If users pushes a button to send time change request, the client sends the new time back to the server, which, upon receiving the REQUEST_TIME_CHANGE string, modifies its time. I really don't get it why the time changes back when a new client is connected. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here's what happens now:

```
Exception in thread "ConnectThread" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or      cancelled
at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Timer.schedule(Unknown Source)
at task2.ConnectThread.run(ConnectThread.java:36)
```

This is probably because I use the same TimerTask to schedule the timer more than once. Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: when you are calling setTime method in ClockTask?

Comment: It's called from within the setCalendarTime, in the main loop of ConnectThread.

Answer (score 2):

Your Class is not actually a Singleton.
Change the getInstance method as follows (keyword synchronized is important).

```
public static synchronized ClockTask getInstance() 
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = new ClockTask();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

And make your constructor as private for preventing Object creation from outside.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable. But now I get IllegalStateException: task already scheduled or cancelled. I'll add the stack trace.